# Bot Builder attachments will not send link Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I'm trying to send some wording wrapped in a link using Bot Builder Framework. My code is as follows:

```
builder.DialogAction.send({

    text: 'Terms & Conditions',
    attachments: [
        {
            contentType: 'text/html',
            contentUrl: 'https://www.mycompany.com/termsandconditions',
            name: 'Terms & Conditions'   
        }
    ]
})(session);
```

This seems to work find with other mime contentTypes like .png and .json. But Im not sure why this doesnt allow for clickable links.

Comment: What channel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To send a text message with a URL, no special configuration is required, just send the URL as plain-text. For example: `session.send('Message with URL: https://botframework.com');`.